# SSRS 13 (SQL 2016) Report Caching Question

Tags: sql-server, caching, reporting-services

We have a report that takes AN AGE to run during the day, mainly due to the fact that the users need to select several parameters as part of their execution on a date range.

What I was hoping was that I could cache the report using a default date range and selecting ALL for the sub-parameter options so that they can run a further filters report based upon the cached data set.

However, when reading this on the MS website, it sounds like it won't work:

**Conditions That Cause Cache Expiration**

A cached report is invalidated in response to the following events: the report definition is modified, report parameters are modified, data source credentials change, or report execution options change. If you delete a report that is stored in the cache, the cached version is also deleted.
If a report cannot be rendered from a cached instance for any reason (for example, if the parameter values that a user specifies are different from those used to produce the cached report), the report server reruns the report.*

After reading this, my belief is that, as they will NOT be using the ALL option from each variable, the report will re-run instead of using the cache.

Is this right?  Is there a way around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the report's data query is run for the parameters and when the parameters change, it re-runs the query because it can't know that the new parameters are for a subset of the data it has already extracted.

If your report is for historical data (i.e. last week, last month) and isn't effected by changes in the data throughout the day, you could consider extracting the report data in a batch process overnight into another database that just holds the data for the report and is optimised with appropriate indices and so forth. Then your report can use the new reporting database and it should be faster.